# C# Selenium (0.24) Firefox new. How to load profile by path?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I tried to load profile by path string but it's not working.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();            
options.Profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"d:\firefox");
options.Profile.SetPreference("privacy.trackingprotection.enabled", true);
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

if add argument it's work but can't automate.

```
options.AddArguments("-profile", @"d:\firefox");
```

Comment: @DebanjanB Your solution for Java, My question for C#. I load profile by folder path, not by profile by name. Thank

Comment: Added relevant C# target

Comment: @DebanjanB driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); is old

Answer (score 0):

See this link:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriverService.htm

```
var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path)
```

Create an instance of the DriverService using a specified path exe.

After that you can create an instance of `RemoteWebDriver` with specified driver service:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver((FirefoxDriverService)driverService, (FirefoxOptions)options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)); //third parameter is a command timeout
```

Comment: var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path); path mean FirefoxBinaryPath not Profile path. Thank you

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriverService_CreateDefaultService_1.htm

CreateDefaultService accept profile path 
@mangovn

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: 'The file .......\bin\Debug\firefox_data\default\geckodriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases'

Comment: What's a path value?
...\source\repos\buyer\buyer\bin\Debug\6vvzzarr.default\  ?

Comment: ...\source\repos\buyer\buyer\bin\Debug\6vvzzarr.default\ is profile path

Comment: documents said 
Parameters
driverPath
Type: System.String
The directory containing the Firefox driver executable.

Comment: is geckodriver.exe  into that path?

Comment: i was tried copy geckodriver.exe into that path, working fine but can''t load profile. Thank

Comment: old gecko driver just driver = new FirefoxDriver(profilepath) but they were removed.